# Understanding a GUID pattern definition in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I recently [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687884/what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-the-guid-type-in-a-xsd-file) following pattern definition that defines a GUID:

```
<xs:pattern value="\{[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}\}"/>
```

I need some help to understand this.  Here are my problems:

```
/ not at the ending, at the begin of the value attribute.
- between the letter definition(ex:[a-fA-F0-9]).
```

It's not explained at the w3 site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Point 1:**

> ```
> / not at the ending, at the begin of the value attribute.
> ```

The only `/` in the `xs:pattern` you show is part of the XML syntax for a [**empty-element tag**](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-empty).  This is a normal XML construct unrelated to the pattern being defined for a GUID; it could equivalently have been written with an explicit closing tag:

```
<xs:pattern value="..."></xs:pattern>
```

**Point 2:**

> ```
> - between the letter definition(ex:[a-fA-F0-9]).
> ```

The `-` in `[]` signifies a range in regular expressions.   So, `[a-f]` allows all letters from `a` to `f`, inclusive.   The entire `[a-fA-F0-9]` allows all hexadecimal digits.

**Some other points you didn't ask about:**

- The `\{` or `\}` means that a literal `{` or `}` is expected.
- The `{8}` means that 8 of the preceding subpattern (hex digits) are
  expected.
- The `-` outside of `[]` means that a literal `-` is expected.

**So, together, this pattern is matching GUIDs wrapped in `{ }`, e.g:**

```
{90B1532C-3611-48D8-BBAB-D44855FA73BD}
```

Comment: I tried to ask for point 1 and 3 of your aditional points ;) But thank iam understanding the pattern defintion now...