# How to teach JAXB used by Apache CXF JAX-WS client to unmarshal {http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/}guid values in an untyped property?

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf, jax-ws, soap-client

I have a SOAP service I need to send requests to (specifically [Ivanti Integration Web Service](https://help.ivanti.com/ht/help/en_US/ISM/2017.3/Content/Configure/Develop/Web%20Service.htm)).

I use Apache CXF 3.2.7 to connect to the service. I generate Java classes from the service’s WSDL using `wsdl2java`.

The WSDL makes no mention of any GUIDs and seems entirely self-sufficient. However, there is one field (named `Value`) that is untyped, i. e. an `xsd:element` without a `type` attribute, and the server sends responses with values of various types in this field. They look like this:

- ```xml
  <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">foobar</Value>
  ```
- ```xml
  <Value xsi:type="xsd:short">1</Value>
  ```
- ```xml
  <Value xsi:type="q2:guid" xmlns:q2="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/">c3aca40a-439d-4af2-b42e-59b1ddcf3d6e</Value>
  ```

Strings and shorts are fine, but the GUIDs produce this exception on the client:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unrecognized type name: {http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/}guid
```

**How do I avoid this exception?** I don’t actually care about the value of this field, although a solution that achieves type-safe unmarshalling would, of course, be ideal.

### What I’ve tried

No matter what I do, the exception just doesn’t go away. In particular, I’ve tried:

- adding `<jaxb:binding><jaxb:property><jaxb:baseType>` to my customized binding XML to make it treat the field as a string—it made the Java property a string but apparently kept unmarshaling data according to the specified types and broke because it coudn’t convert a date to a string;
- adding `<jaxb:javaType>` or `<jxc:javaType>` with a custom unmarshalling method—this didn’t work at all, `wsdl2java` failed with “compiler was unable to honor this conversion customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings” no matter where I placed the element and no matter what Java type I specified;
- manually adding the type definition from [one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj675594(v=office.12).aspx) of [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh626737(v=office.12).aspx) [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/723045/865331):

  ```xml
  <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="guid">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:schema>
  ```

  to the service’s WSDL file before invoking `wsdl2java` on it—after adding an `xsd:element` in addition to the `xsd:simpleType`, I finally got `wsdl2java` to generate a method on `ObjectFactory` annotated with `@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/", name = "guid")`, but this method still wasn’t used, plain `String` was still used wherever my WSDL referred to `guid`, and the `UnmarshalException` persisted;
- even adding an in-`Interceptor` on the `USER_STREAM` phase that eats up the entire `InputStream` into a string, brutally finds all things that look like the GUID `xsi:type`/`xmlns:q2` attributes and replaces them with `xsi:type="xsd:string"` similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12948702/865331)—but I must have made some mistake, because the exception *still* didn’t go away; here’s my code:

  ```java
  import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
  import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
  import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
  import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
  import org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor;
  import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;

  public class GuidExpungeInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
    private static class GuidExpungedInputStream extends ByteArrayInputStream {
      private final InputStream stream;

      public GuidExpungedInputStream(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        super(guidExpungedByteArray(stream));
        this.stream = stream;
      }

      private static byte[] guidExpungedByteArray(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        String content = IOUtils.toString(stream, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        content = content.replaceAll("<Value xsi:type=\"([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_.-]*):guid\" xmlns:\\1=\"http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/\">", "<Value xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">");
        return content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
      }

      @Override
      public void close() throws IOException {
        stream.close();
        super.close();
      }
    }

    public GuidExpungeInterceptor() {
      super(Phase.USER_STREAM);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
      if (message == message.getExchange().getInMessage()) {
        try {
          InputStream stream = message.getContent(InputStream.class);
          message.setContent(InputStream.class, new GuidExpungedInputStream(stream));
        } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new Fault(e);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  ```java
  class BlahController {
    BlahController() {
      JaxWsProxyFactoryBean proxyFactory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
      proxyFactory.setServiceClass(FRSHEATIntegrationSoap.class);
      proxyFactory.setAddress(this.properties.getFrsHeatIntegrationUrl());
      this.service = (FRSHEATIntegrationSoap) proxyFactory.create();

      Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(service);
      client.getInInterceptors().add(new GuidExpungeInterceptor());
    }
  }
  ```

  Then I use `this.service` to invoke the strongly typed operation methods. Perhaps the interceptor isn’t preserved beyond the local `client` variable?

If I understand correctly (which I’m not at all sure about), this exception means that JAXB doesn’t have an unmarshaller registered for the GUID type and it should be resolved if I could somehow get a hold on the JAXB registry and add my own marshaller. But after looking at CXF’s JavaDocs, I have no idea how, or even if, I could gain access to this registry. Some methods sound like I might be able to get a `JAXBContext`, but I don’t see how I could add anything to an already existing `JAXBContext` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import the sources generated by `wsdl2java` from your original WSDL into your source control (and stop generating them on every build), you can add a custom class mapping the `simpleType`:

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

@XmlType(namespace = "http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/", name = "guid")
public class Guid {
   @XmlValue
   public String guid;
}
```

and add a `@XmlSeeAlso(Guid.class)` annotation to one of your `wsdl2java`-generated classes that are already being picked up by JAXB, e. g. the actual service class. The service class probably already has `@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})`, so you can just change that to `@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class, Guid.class})`.

This way, JAXB will successfully unmarshal the GUIDs as `Guid` instances with plain string contents. If you want actual `java.util.UUID` instances, you may be able to add `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` on the `@XmlValue` field, but I haven’t tested this.

(By the way: when you tried adding `xsd:element` to the WSDL, I think you added a mapping for an *XML element* named `guid`, e. g. `<q2:guid xmlns:q2="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/">c3aca40a-439d-4af2-b42e-59b1ddcf3d6e</q2:guid>`. This isn’t what you wanted, so this explains why it didn’t help you.)